# Using Quasar Notify plugin in Storybook mdx file (Quasar v2, Storybook, Vue3)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, storybook, quasar-framework, quasar

I'm having some issues with the Notify plugin from Quasar. I have already defined the plugin in quasar.config.js and made the necessary imports according to the Quasar documentation. However, I am still facing the error of $q.notify being undefined in the .mdx story file. In Quasar V1, the error was not generated and the code works fine. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested, I solved it by adding the following in the storybook preview.js file:

```
app.use(Quasar, {
  plugins: {
    Notify,
  },
  config: {
    notify:{},
  },
}
```